# How to write assertion to validate the data selected in webpage is storing properly in database?

Tags: javascript, mysql, typescript, protractor

I have a scenario in protractor automation where i have validate the values selected via radio button on webpage is reflecting in the database or not. How to proceed on this?

Comment: you need to show what you tried and why it didn't work. Currently the question is too broad

Comment: i have provided everything in detail in this link: https://stackoverflow.com/q/64219479/14331927

Comment: this question was asked after that one. If they have the same purpose, this one can be closed